# Upgrading AdMob SDK and fail on load() method

Tags: android, admob

I've been working to update to the new AdMob that requires google services to function.
I'm using this code in onCreate()

```
AdView adView = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
//AdRequest
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR).build();
adView.loadAd(adRequest);
Log.d("ADMOB", "Successfully loaded");
```

and am using this code in XML

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/adView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
ads:adUnitId="ADMOB_ID"/>
```

However, the adMob ad does not display. The try/catch block fails here:

```
adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

The AndroidManifest code looks like this:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
```

What am I missing?

Comment: What do you mean "The try/catch block fails here:". Does it throw an Exception? If so, post it. If it is a NullPointerException then it means it has not found your AdView.

Comment: no NPE in fact it only lists the debug stuff that I inserted which is showing me that it fails at the build(). I'm about to try on a real device as the emulator doesn't seem to be functioning properly.

Comment: What do you mean 'fails at the build()'. What are the symptoms? How does it fail?

Comment: I don't see any stack trace. I think there are wider issues with how Android is installed on my Mac. I'll look and get back to you with some more information.

Answer (score 1):

Referring to the [AdMob Android Guides](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/android/quick-start) I quote

> Next, create the onActivityCreated method. This is where you'll build and load the AdRequest. Reference the AdView, then build and load the AdRequest.

So, you must implement it like following :

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle bundle) 
{
  super.onActivityCreated(bundle);
  AdView mAdView = (AdView) getView().findViewById(R.id.adView);
  AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
  mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
}
```

Comment: are you suggesting that I move it out of the onCreate() and create an onActivityCreated() method? Also, the getView() suggested causes errors as well.

Comment: Yes.Try to follow the tutorial I have mentioned in my answer please.

Comment: I get a blank space but no log details or ad displayed.

Comment: All right, I tested this tutorial and it works for me : http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/integrating-new-google-admob-banner-interstitial-ads/

Comment: What's the error ? It worked for me without any problem.

Comment: The problem was that no ads were being displayed. The issue ended up being incorrect ID's in each place. The fact that there are now 2 different types of ID's meant that I needed to mess around with where each ID went to get the test ads to appear. Thanks for the assistance, I voted you up @Farouk Touzi as yours was the most helpful response.